# Ho to make a prediction for a single sample with CatBoost?

Tags: python, prediction, catboost

So I've trained a CatBoost Classifier model with some data that includes some categorical variables; the problem is that I want to make a prediction for a single sample but I always get an error; like this:

```
# X is a dataframe with 23 vars, 14 of which are categorical
model.predict(X.loc[1])  # This gives the error below

CatBoostError: Invalid cat_features[1] = 1 value: index must be < 1.


# I've tried reshaping the series but this raises another error
model.predict(X.loc[1].values.reshape(1, -1)) # This form works with LightGBM

CatBoostError: 'data' is numpy array of floating point numerical type, it means no categorical 
features, but 'cat_features' parameter specifies nonzero number of categorical features
```

However, if I try with two or more samples it works perfectly

```
model.predict(X.iloc[:2,:]) 

array([1., 0])
```

I don't understand how to just make one simple prediction, I haven't found information about this.

¿How to make a prediction for a single sample with catboost?

Answer (score 1):

That's how `sklearn` API works. You need to pass a collection to `predict` method. Just wrap your sample in a list.

```py
model.predict([X.loc[1]])
```